# sqlite3 strftime not returning anything

Tags: sql, sqlite, strftime

I am using sqlite 3 turn a date stored as text like this "2018-06-03 20:11:53.784 UTC" into "2018-06-03"

I have tried:
select updated_at, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', updated_at) from table_1;

where updated_at has the format stated above,"2018-06-03 20:11:53.784 UTC"

However, in return, I get just a column of the updated_at and a comma. That is it. strftime('%Y-%m-%d', updated_at) part is not returning anything.

I am thinking the strftime doesn't understand the current format. Anything would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Update the table by replacing the 'UTC' part the text with ''. After this step, the strftime should recognize the text as date.